# My MacBook Pro 15 2018 is too hot

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature, touch-bar, macos

I bought a 15'' MacBook Pro a few days ago and it gets too hot under load. Idle temperatures are about 40-50 degrees light use 60 degrees but opening a light game like league of legends will set the CPU at 80-90 degrees.
I want to know if this is normal or not and if it will damage my battery.I still have time to return the laptop. Thank you.

Comment: Unless the place you bought it from is inconveniently far away I would suggest that you take it back there and point out your issues and see what they say. Or, since this is a *brand new* computer you could call Apple support. Just sayin'

Comment: So, is it normal to get 90 degrees under load or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the normal operating temperature for the MacBook (2016 generation)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237628/what-is-the-normal-operating-temperature-for-the-macbook-2016-generation)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean 40-50 degrees C, not F.

Yes, that's pretty normal. I'm just browsing the web with Safari, and my laptop is at 111 degress F

Comment: And when using some light programs at the same time I around 60 C - 150 F is that normal? Will it hurt my battery?

Comment: I do quite a bit of video editing and compiling, as well as run VM’s and Docker. Frequently, the temperature for my Mac will bounce to just under 100 C, just below boiling. I often set a fan override with iStat menus that ramps the fans to max when a sensor goes above 150 F.

Comment: Remember: Processors produce work as a byproduct of converting electricity to heat. The speed of your processor doesn’t matter as much as how much heat the thermal enclosure can dissipate and how efficient the processor is. With Turbo Boost, a water cooled 2.5 GHz Core i7 can be much faster than a 4.0 GHz Core i7 with radiative cooling. And don’t get me started on the Core i9 fiasco.

Comment: don't mix temperature scales; unless the reader is american, they won't understand Feinheit